# Dynamic switch cases in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

Is there anyway we can generate dynamic switch cases in Dart? I am making error handler for my API response status code. An example would look like this:

```
http.Response response = await http.post("api url here", body: jsonMap);
switch (response.statusCode) {
  case (200):
    await showSuccessDialog();
    // handles on success
  case (400):
    // show error message for status code 400
  case (500):
    // show error message for status code 500
  default:
    break;
}
```

I want to make a global function of sort so I can reuse this function whenever there is an API call. To do this, I would need a custom List of error messages corresponding to each error code. In my mind, the global function switch case would look like this, with passing of `_customMessage` as `List<map>`.

```
List<Map> customMessages = [
  {"error_code": 400, "message": "Error 400"},
  {"error_code": 402, "message": "Error 402"}
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var jsonMap; // handle jsonMap here
          http.Response response =
              await http.post("api url here", body: jsonMap);
          errorDialogs(context, response.statusCode, customMessages);
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void errorDialogs(BuildContext _context, int _statusCode, List<Map> _customMessages) {
  // below switch statement is wrong but putting it here to get the idea across
  switch (_statusCode) {
    _customMessages.forEach((error){
      case (error["error_code"]): 
        //show dialog with error["error_message"]
    }
  }
}
```

So the problem lies in this, the above is definitely wrong but that's the idea. How do I make dynamic switch cases so it can generate switch cases based on a List of error message that I pass in to this function? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Edited code to show how I would apply the function `errorDialogs`.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```dart
Map<String, void Function()> functionMap = {
  'a': () => print('A'),
  'b': () => print('B'),
  'c': () => print('C'),
  'd': () => print('D'),
  'e': () => print('E'),
};

void main() {
  final x = 'c';
  print('CASE $x:');
  functionMap[x].call();
}
```

Result:

```
CASE c:
C
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To fit this functionMap into my context, I would need dynamic amount of functions which is dependent on the number of different status code I have for each API call. Is it possible to pass in more functions to this functionMap?

Comment: Definitely. Could you provide an example of such a function? How do you create these functions?

Comment: I have edited my questions with an example function "errorDialogs".