# Dynamically generate new Switch Cases in Switch Statement flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

Is there a way to create or insert switch case inside the switch statement dynamically in flutter.

```
String getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName(String blNodeClassName){
    //print("className> "+blNodeClassName.toString());
    switch(blNodeClassName){
      case "BLNodeBSFileUploader":       //<-- these are class names of dart file (node file).
        return "File Uploader";
      case "BLNodeTusFileUploader":
        return "TUS File Uploader";
      case "BLNodeFilePicker":
        return "File Picker";
      case "BLNodeFunction":
        return "Function";
      case "BLNodeSimpleHttp":
        return "Simple Http";
      case "BLNodeUriToEncode":
        return "Uri Encode";
    }
}
```

whenever i create a new node file i have to manually create a switch case in switch statement, and these types of switch functionality are also present in other files also.

So i have to create a switch case at around 4 different location.

Is there is a way to generate these switch case dynamically as i create a new node file.
The only question regarding my problem but can't solve my purpose [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424374/dynamic-switch-cases-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

If that switch method always receive String and return String,
how about you use Map?

[image]

```
String getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName(String blNodeClassName){
    //print("className> "+blNodeClassName.toString());
    switch(blNodeClassName){
      case "BLNodeBSFileUploader":       //<-- these are class names of dart file (node file).
        return "File Uploader";
      case "BLNodeTusFileUploader":
        return "TUS File Uploader";
      case "BLNodeFilePicker":
        return "File Picker";
      case "BLNodeFunction":
        return "Function";
      case "BLNodeSimpleHttp":
        return "Simple Http";
      case "BLNodeUriToEncode":
        return "Uri Encode";
    }
  return '';
}

Map<String, dynamic> getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName2 = {
 'BLNodeBSFileUploader': 'File Uploader',
 'BLNodeTusFileUploader': 'TUS File Uploader',
 'BLNodeFilePicker': 'File Picker',
 'BLNodeFunction': 'Function',
 'BLNodeSimpleHttp': 'Simple Http',
 'BLNodeUriToEncode': 'Uri Encode',
};

void main() {


  print('getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName>> ${getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName('BLNodeBSFileUploader')}');
  print('getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName2>> ${getRCMenuNameFromBLNodeClassName2['BLNodeBSFileUploader']}');
    

}
```

Comment: see there are 100's of switch cases in my case, i have just share a piece of code, at this point i can't change the whole function with map, also these types of switch function are present at other location also, if there is a way to generate them dynamically from list or something like that.